# Bizarre AJAX response codes

Tags: javascript, ajax, http

Occasionally, but more often than I'd like, AJAX calls just don't work in IE (testing in IE9)

Sometimes, the request is logged as sent in the Network tab of Developer Tools, but stays "pending" indefinitely and is never actually received by the server.

Other times, the request comes back with an HTTP code that is unlike anything I've ever seen: well into the 12xxx range...

No other site I've been on that uses AJAX has this problem, so why am I getting such issues?

Comment: It's just your standard `a=new XMLHttpRequest(); a.open('GET',url,true); a.onreadystatechange = function() {...}; a.send();`, nothing special.

Comment: I recommend using other tools besides the IE9 developer tool. Try http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/ if you haven't already.

Comment: It would be extremely useful to actually write what it is that fixed your issue. I am facing a similar problem and would like to find out what is causing it. Thanks in advance

Comment: I used a workaround, testing if the response code is greater than 999 and if so just silently retrying the connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[System Error Codes (12XXX)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385465%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Okay, the one I was getting sometimes was `12152 ERROR_HTTP_INVALID_SERVER_RESPONSE`. That would suggest that my server is at fault, but the error has never occurred on Chrome (or, again, on other sites that use AJAX). This doesn't really make sense to me because the server still never received the request in the first place...

Comment: Have you looked at it with Fiddler and look at the request and response?

Comment: I implemented "try up to five times" if such an error code is received.